# How to use ddply or dplyr to evaluate a multivariable function with unvectorized inputs against a data frame?

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to run a numerical simulation across a range of points from a data set created with expand grid. I'd like to use `plyr` or `dplyr` for this if possible. However, I don't understand the syntax.

Is there a small perturbation on the code below that applies the values of x and y individually against f?

```
f <- function(x, y) {
    A <- data_frame(a = x*runif(100) - y)
    B <- data_frame(b = A$a - rnorm(100)*y)
    sum(A$a) - sum(B$b)
}

X <- expand.grid(x = 1:10, y = 2:8)
X %>% mutate(z = f(x, y))
```

I had hoped `ddply` might make this easier.

EDIT: This seems to behave as intended:

```
 X %>% ddply(.(x, y), transform, z = f(x, y))
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Is there any grouping? Or are you just doing the same thing to every row?

Comment: I want to do the same thing to every row: use the values in each row to evaluate the function. I'm tripping up on `sum` I think. There is no grouping.

Comment: without something to group_by, you may as well just use a normal mapply function, rather than ddply or dplyr. `X$z<-mapply(f,X$x,X$y)`

Comment: Also, the `data_frame`s in your function aren't doing anything useful, deleting them will make your function more efficient.

Comment: what's a `data_frame`? [`plyr::mdply`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/441) sounds like a possible solution

Comment: @baptiste `data_frame()` is a stripped-down `dplyr` version of `data.frame()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite your function to do the same thing without the `data_frame` calls, just using vectors will be faster:

```
f <- function(x, y) {
    a = x * runif(100) - y
    b = a - rnorm(100) * y
    sum(a) - sum(b)
}
```

Since you want to apply this to every row, you could do it with `plyr` or `dplyr`. These tools are made for "split-apply-combine", where you you split a data frame into pieces by some grouper, do something to each piece, and put it back together. You want to something to every individual row, so we set both `x` and `y` as grouping variables, which works because a combination of x and y uniquely defines a row:

```
# plyr
ddply(X, .(x, y), plyr::mutate, z = f(x, y))

# dplyr
group_by(X, x, y) %>% dplyr::mutate(z = f(x, y))
```

For both `plyr` and `dplyr`, the `mutate` function is used because you want to add a column to an existing data frame, keeping the same number of rows. The other common function to use is `summarize`, which is used when you want to condense groups that have multiple rows into a single summary row. `mutate` is very similar to `base::transform`.

There is really no advantage to using `plyr` for data frame manipulation, `dplyr` is faster and most people think easier to understand. It really shines when you have more complex manipulations and are using groups rather than individual rows. For individual rows, the base function `mapply` works well:

```
X$z = mapply(f, X$x, X$y)
```

(thanks to @jeremycg in the comments). You can use `dplyr` but there's no  reason to do so in this case.

Comment: `plyr::mdply(X, f)` is the only reason I still prefer plyr over dplyr

Comment: That does look nice, I've never used it. I still pull out plyr for `ldply`, `llply`, etc.